# AWS S3 : is it risky to set "Block all public access" to off?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to share some public assets (images and fonts) with anyone who has the URL (read only).

I uploded the files to a new S3 bucket.

- In **Permissions > Block public access** I set everything to **Off**
- In **Properties > Static website hosting** I configured it as **Use this bucket to host a website**

Is it risky ? Can anybody write in my bucket because I set **Block Public access** to **Off** ?

Comment: It depends on how you set the bucket policy.

Comment: What if I keep it empty ? Currently I can read my objects and I have no policy. My concern is about the write permissions.

Comment: Related to your comment that "I want to share some public assets ... with anyone who has the URL", just be aware that these assets will be available to anyone, not just those that you might share the URL with. There are plenty of people who scan random S3 bucket names to detect public assets. They don't need to know the URL in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normally done  when setting bucket in website mode. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteAccessPermissionsReqd.html):

> To make your bucket publicly readable, you **must disable** block public access settings for the bucket

What others can do, depends on [bucket policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-2). For website, it should only allow **read only access**:

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"PublicRead",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see, the policy **allows only** `s3:GetObject`.  `s3:PutObject` is not included which would allow writing to the bucket.

---

Comment: The Bucket Policy is empty right now, thanks for the sample ;-)

Comment: Do you know what is the default behavior ? Is it blocked by default and you have to explcitely give access to people in the policy ?

Comment: @maxime No problem. If its empty then nothing is allowed. You have to allow read-only for others to be able to view it.

Comment: @maxime Everything in AWS is private by default. So without the policy, your content can't be accessed anonymously.